# 1991 MS-DOS laptop - how can I read the data from this disk?

Tags: hard-drive

I would like to know what kind of connector does this hard drive have? It was used in a MS-DOS laptop from 1991 and it probably had a 40MB disk capacity. The connector is in the bottom right and includes power as well.

- Drive: Conner Peripherals CP-4044 ([link1](https://stason.org/TULARC/pc/hard-drives-hdd/conner/CP-4044XT-42MB-3-5-SSL-IDE-XT.html), [link2](http://theref.mfarris.com/hard_drives/conner_peripherals/conner_peripherals_cp-4044_stubby.html))
- Connector: 2 x 22 pins, 27mm wide
- Drive dimensions: 10,0 x 13,0 cm

**The purpose is to read the data on the disk and to wipe the disk afterwards. So besides knowing this, what do I need to connect it to another working computer?**

[image: 1991 40MB hard disk]

[image: Conner Peripherals CP-4044]

[image: IDE XT]

Comment: Can you measure approximately how wide the connector is? It looks like it's 2x22 pins, is that correct?

Comment: I updated the question.

Answer (score 1):

It’s some form of (parallel) IDE. It looks like a 44 pin variant, which was used mainly for 2.5” (laptop) drives. This type of connector combines power and data.

More common variants for 3.5” (and larger) drives have separate power (4-pin) and data (40-pin) and have a larger form factor.

If you manage to find the drive make and model I can be more specific.

Comment: I updated the question!